# Map Annotations not visible on map

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotation

I'm trying to display the annotations for building entrances on a MapKit map in my application.

To do so I have created a class `EntranceAnnotation` implementing `MKAnnotation` so that I can later implement a custom `MKAnnotationView` for these. For the purpose of this question though I'm also experiencing the problem when trying to solve this with simple `MKPointAnnotation`s.

I am using a custom subclass of `MKMapView` inside of which the following code resides.

```
let entranceAnnotations: [MKPointAnnotation] = selectedBuilding.entrances.map { 
    entrance in
    let ann = MKPointAnnotation()
    ann.coordinate = entrance.location
    return ann
}
addAnnotations(entranceAnnotations)
```

If I check the `mapView`s list of annotations before and after calling `addAnnotations` on it, I can see that the added ones are definitely appearing in the list.

I currently do not have `view(for annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?` overridden, as this shouldn't be necessary for simple `MKPointAnnotation`s. But even if I do, and return new instances of `MKPinAnnotationView` with a given color, this seems to have no effect. Whatever I'm doing, these annotations are not appearing on my map.

Is there something I could be missing here? Even trying to add a single simple new annotation fails to have an effect.

```
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.028500, longitude: 13.728653)
addAnnotation(annotation)
```

If it makes a difference, I am trying to run this on the iOS 10 Beta 14A5309d with Xcode 8 Beta 3.

Comment: Are you adding annotations on the main thread?

Comment: I've tried wrapping the `addAnnotations` call in either `OperationQueue.main.addOperation{}` or `DispatchQueue.main.async{}`, both to no avail unfortunately.

Comment: Ok, well, `mapView` has a delegate that conforms to `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol. Try to debug mapView for `fullyRendered` in next function - `func mapViewDidFinishRenderingMap(mapView: MKMapView, fullyRendered: Bool)`. Maybe you adding an annotations before map is fully rendered...

Comment: Definitely seems to be the case. The annotations in question are only added to the map after the user selects a building.

Comment: By "definitely seems to be the case" I meant that the view definitely is fully rendered.

Comment: Ok, need dive deeper :) Does mapview have a `delegate` object that is not `nil`?

Comment: It does, the view controller displaying the map is set as its delegate.

Comment: Got it, sorry, have no more fresh ideas ...

Comment: Thank you nevertheless! Doing some more debugging at least is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this myself. My custom subclass of `MKAnnotationView` relied on some initialization done in my override of `initWithFrame:` and up to iOS 10, initializing the annotationView by calling `initWithAnnotation:reuseIdentifier:` would eventually call down into initWithFrame:. Starting in iOS 10, though, `initWithFrame:` is never called. The result of this was that my custom annotations had a frame of `(0, 0, 0, 0)` and did not display. Adding

```
[self setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, someWidth, someHeight];
```

inside `initWithAnnotation:reuseIdentifier:` made the annotations appear again under iOS10. Obviously requires some work to map to an equivalent Swift solution, but this could well be your issue. Set breakpoints in your initializers and see which one(s) get hit!